# How to make multiple TCP connection via different port?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have tried to made TCP connection via ports to check whether the ports are opened or not.

```
Param (
        [string] $IPAddress,
        $Ports
    )

$t = New-Object Net.Sockets.TcpClient

$PortArray= $Ports -split ","

Foreach ($Port in $PortArray) {

    $t.Connect($Ipaddress,$Port)

    if($t.Connected)
    {
        "Port $Port is operational"
    }
    else
    {
        "Port $Port is Not opened . Request port access via IT support team. "
    }

    $t.Close()  
}
```

I called the function like below.

```
PS D:\PowerCLi-Scripts> .\Is-PortOpened.ps1 -IPAddress "193.44.35.234" -Port ("443,902,903")
```

When connecting to the second and third port it throws error as follows.

> Exception calling "Connect" with "2" argument(s): "Cannot access a
>   disposed obj ect.

Though i have given $t.close(). I am still facing the issue.

Can somebody help me to resolve this?

Comment: Note you don't need to declare `Ports` as a string, then split it into an array.  Declare it as an array to being with - `[string[]] $Ports`, and call the script like `-Ports 443,902,903` or `-Ports '443','902','903'`

Comment: @latkin Thanks buddy . I have added your suggested change in my script. Now it looks nice .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation(MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.close.aspx), the `Close` method marks the socket as disposed. This means you cannot reuse the same instance, and need to create a new `TcpClient` instance before attempting a connect. Moving the line starting with `$t = ...` into the foreach loop, and you should be OK.